# Json .net. Select converter based on message fields

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have, maybe, a strange use-case and will also be very gratefull, if my problem can be solved in another way.

I have an app, which listen's to incoming event's (json messages) and invokes some code, based on message type. It looks something like this:

```
_queue.Subscribe(message =>
{
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(message, _serializationSettings);

    lock (this)
    {
        var type = obj.GetType();
        typeof(IEventStorage)
              .GetMethod(nameof(IEventStorage.ProcessEvent))
              .MakeGenericMethod(type)
              .Invoke(EventsStorage, new[] { obj });
    }

    return true;
});
```

Here i deserialize incoming message to my app data type and then, based on this type, invoke `ProcessEvent` method, which signature looks like this:

```
void ProcessEvent<TEvent>(TEvent dto) where TEvent : IEvent;
```

Everything was great until i needed to modify my data types so that now i have to use custom converters, to read incoming json. Now, i face a problem in DeserializeObject, because Newtonsoft json cannot understand the need to use converter to deserialize. In my messages i have `$type` member, which i can use to choose right converter for deserialization, but i cannot understand, how to specify this in converter or contract resolver.

I'll be very gratefull for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an overload of `Deserialize<>()` that accepts a collection of `JsonConverter`s. Each `JsonConverter` has a method `CanConvert`. So the `Deserialize<>()` method will examine the converters you provide and use the first one that `CanConvert`

You can create a single `Converter` that return true in `CanConvert()` and in `ReadJson()`, it examines the message and decides on the deserialization strategy (maybe using othe classes you've already created)

Comment: Well, this doesn't look very beautiful, but works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Can you elaborate on why you think this is not a clean solution?

Comment: The problem of this solution for me is that if someday i'll want to receive regular messages, which don't need some specific converter, i'll need to modify this one anyway, because i cannot choose deserialization strategy based on fields of JSON (ofc i can implement this by myself, but it's not a general solution)

Comment: Ah, now I see, you're right. In this case, you can apply `JsonConverterAttribute` to your base class, and the converter you provide will examine the json content to decide which concrete class to deserialize to. Then `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>()` will automatically use your converter, only if `T` inherits from your base class.

Comment: Your solution looks great, but all the problems began because i couldn't use generic version of DeserializeObject since i don't know the real type of incoming message (that's why i use $type attribute.). I didn't describe this part in my question exactly (i mentioned `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(message, _serializationSettings);` but it doesn't have the `<T>` part and so converter must guess the type himself. After that i can construct generic method based on GetType of deserialized object). My fault, certainly

Comment: If I've understood correctly, the exact problem is this: you can't call the generic version of `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>()` because you don't know the exact target `Type` until you examine the message contents. Not all the target types you are interested in deserializing inherit from a base class, so my previous comment is not applicable, and you want your messages to deserialize to the correct `Type`?

Am I right in all my assumptions?